# How to search more fields using single text field textbox

Tags: search, views

I have a content type with fields title, body, short description & long description. In view i added these fields. i need to add an exposed search text-field in view to search the search term in title, body, short description & long description fields. Views search term is not happening for me. Combine search is only taking maximum 2 fields. Please help

Comment: You want to search for title in views page?

Comment: Not only title. I need to search title, body, short description & long description fields in a single textfield.

Comment: ok..now you can folllow these lines..views->ciclk filter creteria-->add title field--->then click on grouped filter in title field settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a solution for this problem. I added a field to my content type and made it hidden. In my hook_pre_save, i merged all my fields data together separated by a space and saved that data to my hidden field. in my exposed filter form, i added the hidden field and exposed it to user to search.

Answer (score 1):

It's Global: Combine fields filter.

Follow Up:-

**process No 1:-**

> Add fields to filter criteria
>
> Add Global: Combine fields filter to filter criteria
>
> Check fields you want to combine in filter's settings

**Process No 2:-**

> Add Fields
>
> Install  [Views filters populate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate).
>
> Add Global:Populate filters  to filter criteria
>
> Check fields you want to combine in filter's settings

I think this answers are resolved your problem.

Comment: process No 1 i failing before itself. I tried Process No 2 with  Views filters populate module (7.x-1.1+1-dev) and exposed it. But the search text-field is not showing.

Comment: Please visit this link once for process No 2:--https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/views-exposed-filters-multiple-field-search

Comment: I need to search in 4 fields (title, body, short description & long description). Combine search will only add two fields right ?

Comment: I tried three approaches 1. Using search term field in views 2.  Using combine fields in views 3.  Using filter populate field in views. All three are failing. Can i have any luck if i do something with views exposed form alter?